# Woocommerce ajax add to cart animation

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code which updates the cart total in my header via ajax but i also want it to make the count flash or enlarge when a cart item is added to draw the users attention to the header cart link. Any ideas how i can do it ?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_cart_count', 10, 2 );
function add_cart_count( $items, $args ) {

    if ($args->theme_location != 'primary'){

    $items .= '<a class="cart-contents" href="'.WC()->cart->get_cart_url().'">Shopping Bag ('.WC()->cart->cart_contents_count.')</a>';
    $items .= '<div class="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>';

    }


return $items;
}
```

Thanks,

Scott.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at actual animation is pretty crappy, but based on [this answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99191/6477) it would appear that you can do anything you'd like on WooCommerce's `added_to_cart` javascript trigger.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('added_to_cart',function(e,data) {
        console.log('something was added');
        console.log(data);
        $('.cart-contents').animate({font-size: 2em}, 500).animate({font-size: 1em}, 500 );
    });
});
```